# What is a suitable process to eliminate an excess of pyridine from an aqueous solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution

I have a reaction in which pyridin is used as a reagent in excess. The resulting product is water soluble and an anion. Pyridinium there will act as a counter ion. Normally, when the product is soluble in organic solvents pyridine is removed by washing with HCl 1 M or with CuSO4 10%. What is the best way to achieve this when the product is water soluble in comparison? In the moment I would apply these strategies:

1. Applying vacuum and high vacuum until mass is constant (pyridinium salts can not be removed).
2. Setting the pH of the water phase slightly basic to pH 8-9 and (pyridinium pka = 5.2) and so multiple extractions with DCM/water.
3. Applying anionic exchange chromatography (Pyridin is washed through the column. Pyridinium is also replaced as a cation by a cation that is present in the mobile phase).

I am wondering if this is already the best possible approach or if you know of a means to remove pyridine more elegantly?

Comment: Do you have access to a freeze-drier?

Comment: What is the composition of the aqueous solution, apart from pyridinium ? I it acid ? basic ? Is there some ethanol ?`some ether ? some inorganic compound ?

Comment: @ Waylander: Access to liquid nitrogen, high vacuum (10^-3 mbar) and a lyophilization system (1 mbar).

Comment: @Maurice: The aqueous phase will contain the product, pyridinium as well as an excess of pyridine. No ethanol, no ether. Basic due to pyridin excess.

Comment: @raptorlane  I think freeze-drying under high vac is the easiest way to go if the pyridinium salt is an acceptable form.

Comment: In my case when performing the follow up reaction what seems to work is to extract most of the pyridine under neutral pH to the water phase and rotivap the organic phase. Subsequently applying high vac. For a water soluble compounds removing the excess pyridine takes longer because most goes to the aquos phase. The contamination is not of a problem on my case, but for yield determination it is obviously necessary to have a dry product.